# 'mat-toolbar' is not a known element - Angular 5

Tags: angular-material, angular5

I have created a new project, and I am trying to add `angular-material`.

I have created `material.module.ts` in my `app` folder:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatToolbarModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatToolbarModule
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

and I have imported it into one of my components:

```
import { MaterialModule } from '../material.module';
```

Furthermore, I have set up angular material in `index.html`

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

in my `style.css`

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css';
```

I know that it is working cause I have shown a `material-icon` as a test:

```
<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

but when I try to create the footer it fails and it shows this message:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: The component should be `<mat-icon>`, **not** `<i class="material-icons">`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's because you have to import a module to the module which *contains* the component declaration, **not** into the component itself:

`app.module.ts`

```ts
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    MaterialModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyCoolComponent,
    // ...
  ]
})
```

P.S. The correct way to use a material icon is to use the `MatIcon` component. Example usage:

```html
<mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 16):

**Best way** 
for a quick good fix

```
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
```

in your app.module.ts

then declare MatToolbarModule in your declarations[].

Comment: remember to add the MatToolbarModule into imports section. Maybe not necessary to put into declarations

Answer (score 4):

Works fine for me here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9ckf8

Look over the link and see if there's anything you are missing.

Comment: I do not really get the difference but it seems that if I import it into angular.module.ts it works so I will do it in this way

Answer (score 1):

run ng add @angular/material in your terminal and this will fix your error

Comment: It is not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to import import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar'; and add it in imports array. Also the code for material is maintained in https://github.com/angular/components.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, I realized it was my fault.
I was getting this error because I didn't make the following definition to the App component.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
     AppComponent,
     DataTableComponent,
     PeriodicComponent,
     HeaderComponent -- here is using MatToolbarModule.
   ],
```

[image]

first you have to add the component that uses material dizany component to declarations array.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading or downgrading your angular service extension in your vs code

Name: Angular Language Service
Description: Editor services for Angular templates
Publisher: Angular
VS Marketplace Link: [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template)

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved this issue by making strict as false

Open

> tsconfig.json

```
{ "compilerOptions" : { "strict" : false} }
```

Note:
I have imported MatToolbarModule too

`import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';`

and declared in Imports array